# What is this monster and how do you get it to appear?

Tags: imbroglio

This is an image of a monster that appeared... *somehow* in my game. It's not in the monster list (at least, as of a brand new game or install).

[image: monster]

What is it and when or how does it appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After encountering one, the monster list calls it a "ghost". It says

> Can move through walls.
>
> When killed, stun a random enemy.

One of the developer's design notes says:

> ... I gave curses the extra effect of ghosting...

https://mightyvision.blogspot.com/2016/11/imbroglio-notes-11-spoiler-warning.html

And another says

> ... curses got the default ghost effect...

https://mightyvision.blogspot.com/2016/09/imbroglio-notes-10-more-card.html

Which seems to imply that a tile that curses a monster will *eventually* turn it into a ghost?